# How to store output from printf with formatting in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, printf, echo

I would like to store the output of `printf` with formatting in a variable, but it strips off the formatting for some reason.

This is the correct output

```
$ printf "%-40s %8s %9s  %7s" "File system" "Free" "Refquota" "Free %"
File system                                  Free  Refquota   Free
```

And now the formatting is gone

```
$ A=$(printf "%-40s %8s %9s  %7s" "File system" "Free" "Refquota" "Free %")
$ echo $A
File system Free Refquota Free %
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`echo` will print each of it's arguments in order, separated by one space.  You are passing a bunch of different arguments to `echo`.

The simple solution is to quote `$A`:

```
A=$(printf "%-40s %8s %9s  %7s" "File system" "Free" "Refquota" "Free %")
echo "$A"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are not quoting the variable. If you do, the format will show perfectly:

```
echo "$A"   #although $a would be best, uppercase vars are not good practise
```

That is, your `var=$(printf )` approach is completely fine, you just fail to `echo` properly.

You may want to know why. Find it in [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/40596)

> ### Why do I need to write `"$foo"`? What happens without the quotes?
>
> `$foo` does not mean “take the value of the variable `foo`”. It means
>   something much more complex:
>
> - First, take the value of the variable.  * Field splitting: treat
>     that value as a whitespace-separated list of fields, and build the
>     resulting list. For example, if the variable contains `foo *  bar ​`
>     then the result of this step is the 3-element list `foo`, `*`, `bar`.
>
>   - Filename generation: treat each field as a glob, i.e. as a wildcard pattern, and replace it by the list of file names that match this
>       pattern. If the pattern doesn't match any files, it is left
>       unmodified. In our example, this results in the list containing `foo`,
>       following by the list of files in the current directory, and finally
>       `bar`. If the current directory is empty, the result is `foo`, `*`,
>       `bar`.
>
> Note that the result is a list of strings. There are two contexts in
>   shell syntax: list context and string context. Field splitting and
>   filename generation only happen in list context, but that's most of
>   the time. Double quotes delimit a string context: the whole
>   double-quoted string is a single string, not to be split. (Exception:
>   `"$@"` to expand to the list of positional parameters, e.g. `"$@` is
>   equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3"` if there are three positional
>   parameters. See [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and/94200#94200))
>
> The same happens to command substitution with `$(foo)` or with 
>   `` `foo` ``. On a side note, don't use `` `foo` ``: its quoting rules are
>   weird and non-portable, and all modern shells support `$(foo)` which
>   is absolutely equivalent except for having intuitive quoting rules.
>
> The output of arithmetic substitution also undergoes the same
>   expansions, but that isn't normally a concern as it only contains
>   non-expandable characters (assuming `IFS` doesn't contain digits or
>   `-`).
>
> See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) for more details about the
>   cases when you can leave out the quotes.
>
> Unless you mean for all this rigmarole to happen, just remember to
>   always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions. Do
>   take care: leaving out the quotes can lead not just to errors but to
>   [security
>   holes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells/171347#171347).